# mobx reaction on filtered list

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I want to listen to the change on specific items of list. I used `reaction` on my list and I filtered my list to get the specific items which I need to listen, but `reaction` fires when new new item adds to list (out of my filtered list)

This is my code:

```
const MyCustomModel = types
  .model({
    id: types.identifier,
    start: types.Date,
    end: types.Date,
  });

const MyStore = types
  .model({
    id: types.identifier,
    items: types.map(MyCustomModel),
  })
  .views(self => ({
    get itemsArray() {
      return Array.from(self.items.values());
    },
  }))
  .actions(self => {
    return {
      setListener(start: Date, end: Date) {
        myReactionDisposer = reaction(
          () =>
            self.itemsArray
              .filter(
                item =>
                  item.end.getTime() >= self.start.getTime() &&
                  item.start.getTime() <= self.end.getTime(),
              )
              .map(item=> item),
          () => {
            console.log('my reaction fires!');
            // other codes
          },
        );
      },
  });
```

For example if I listen to the range `2020-09-20 00:00:00` to `2020-09-21 00:00:00`
and I add new item with a start and end value in another day `{start: '2020-09-15 10:00:00' , end: '2020-09-15 16:20:00'}` , the reaction fires!

Comment: So, what is the question? I am not quite get it. You don't want to fire reaction when new item is added?

Answer (score 0):

The reaction will fire every time simply because you are accessing every item in `itemsArray` (filter function).

But you have a choice of what you return from it. So you could return empty array to your side effect, so it knows it shouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it always return new array from data function (Thanks to [urugator](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/2455#issuecomment-695823800))
I need to change `equal` function for my reaction, and it works for me with shallow comparer

```
reaction(data,effect, { equals: comparer.shallow })
```